# How to Communicate with two c# processes with Named Pipes for Network Interprocess

Tags: c#, .net, named-pipes, inter-process-communicat

I have two Clients (Client-PC1 + Client-PC2) on my Network.
On each of that Clients I like to run a small c# Forms/Console Application and I like to communicate between that Applications.

I like to trigger the Application on Client-PC2 from Client-PC1. (in Code-Part: menuItem1_Click)
I already did some research and found this article on TechNet: [How to: Use Named Pipes for Network Interprocess Communication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx)

But I have one mistake or misunderstanding:
On the server side there is a specific number of threads that can be handled (at the moment: numThreads = 4)

So if I trigger from Client-PC1 more then 4 times then the Server side (Client-PC2) is closing the whole application...

How can I change this code to accept more than just 4 requests/triggers?
In total there are only 1-2 Computers that will connect to the server but sending multiple requests.

I think that I make something wrong on the client side after sending the request/trigger?

Any ideas?

**Client Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace NamedPipe_Client
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int numClients = 4;
        private static bool isConnected = false;

        private System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon notifyIcon1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu contextMenu1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem menuItem1;
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program pg = new Program();
            //pg.CreateNotifyicon();
            Application.Run();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        Program()
        {
            CreateNotifyicon();

            // hide application
            System.IntPtr HWnd = FindWindow(null, Application.ExecutablePath);
            if (HWnd != null)
            {
                bool result = ShowWindow(HWnd, 0);
            }
        }

        private void CreateNotifyicon()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.contextMenu1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu();
            this.menuItem1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem();

            // Initialize menuItem1
            this.menuItem1.Index = 0;
            this.menuItem1.Text = "E&xit";
            this.menuItem1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.menuItem1_Click);

            // Initialize contextMenu1
            this.contextMenu1.MenuItems.AddRange(
                  new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem[] { this.menuItem1 });

            // Create the NotifyIcon.
            this.notifyIcon1 = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon(this.components);

            // The Icon property sets the icon that will appear
            // in the systray for this application.
            notifyIcon1.Icon = new Icon("app_icon.ico");

            // The ContextMenu property sets the menu that will
            // appear when the systray icon is right clicked.
            notifyIcon1.ContextMenu = this.contextMenu1;

            // The Text property sets the text that will be displayed,
            // in a tooltip, when the mouse hovers over the systray icon.
            notifyIcon1.Text = "Console App (Console example)";
            notifyIcon1.Visible = true;

            // Handle the DoubleClick event to activate the form.
            notifyIcon1.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.notifyIcon1_DoubleClick);
            notifyIcon1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.notifyIcon1_Click);

        }
        private void notifyIcon1_Click(object Sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("clicked");
        }

        private void notifyIcon1_DoubleClick(object Sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Double clicked");
        }

        private void menuItem1_Click(object Sender, EventArgs e)//on menu click exit.
        {

            //Show application again
            //System.IntPtr HWnd = FindWindow(null, Application.ExecutablePath);
            //if (HWnd != null)
            //{
            //    bool result = ShowWindow(HWnd, 1);
            //}
            NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient =
                        new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "testpipe",
                            PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.None,
                            TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation);

            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to server...\n");

            pipeClient.Connect();

            StreamString ss = new StreamString(pipeClient);
            // Validate the server's signature string 
            if (ss.ReadString() == "I am the one true server!")
            {
                // The client security token is sent with the first write. 
                // Send the name of the file whose contents are returned 
                // by the server.
                //ss.WriteString(@"C:\Test\textfile.txt");
                ss.WriteString("Test");

                // Print the file to the screen.
                Console.Write(ss.ReadString());
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server could not be verified.");
            }

            pipeClient.Close();
        }

        // Helper function to create pipe client processes 
        private static void StartClients()
        {
            int i;
            string currentProcessName = Environment.CommandLine;
            Process[] plist = new Process[numClients];

            Console.WriteLine("Spawning client processes...\n");

            if (currentProcessName.Contains(Environment.CurrentDirectory))
            {
                currentProcessName = currentProcessName.Replace(Environment.CurrentDirectory, String.Empty);
            }

            // Remove extra characters when launched from Visual Studio
            currentProcessName = currentProcessName.Replace("\\", String.Empty);
            currentProcessName = currentProcessName.Replace("\"", String.Empty);

            for (i = 0; i < numClients; i++)
            {
                // Start 'this' program but spawn a named pipe client.
                plist[i] = Process.Start(currentProcessName, "spawnclient");
            }
            while (i > 0)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < numClients; j++)
                {
                    if (plist[j] != null)
                    {
                        if (plist[j].HasExited)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Client process[{0}] has exited.",
                                plist[j].Id);
                            plist[j] = null;
                            i--;    // decrement the process watch count
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Thread.Sleep(250);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nClient processes finished, exiting.");
        }
    }

    // Defines the data protocol for reading and writing strings on our stream 
    public class StreamString
    {
        private Stream ioStream;
        private UnicodeEncoding streamEncoding;

        public StreamString(Stream ioStream)
        {
            this.ioStream = ioStream;
            streamEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
        }

        public string ReadString()
        {
            int len;
            len = ioStream.ReadByte() * 256;
            len += ioStream.ReadByte();
            byte[] inBuffer = new byte[len];
            ioStream.Read(inBuffer, 0, len);

            return streamEncoding.GetString(inBuffer);
        }

        public int WriteString(string outString)
        {
            byte[] outBuffer = streamEncoding.GetBytes(outString);
            int len = outBuffer.Length;
            if (len > UInt16.MaxValue)
            {
                len = (int)UInt16.MaxValue;
            }
            ioStream.WriteByte((byte)(len / 256));
            ioStream.WriteByte((byte)(len & 255));
            ioStream.Write(outBuffer, 0, len);
            ioStream.Flush();

            return outBuffer.Length + 2;
        }
    }
}
```

**Server Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace NamedPipe_Server
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int numThreads = 4;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i;
            Thread[] servers = new Thread[numThreads];

            Console.WriteLine("\n*** Named pipe server stream with impersonation example ***\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client connect...\n");
            for (i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
            {
                servers[i] = new Thread(ServerThread);
                servers[i].Start();
            }
            Thread.Sleep(250);
            while (i > 0)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < numThreads; j++)
                {
                    if (servers[j] != null)
                    {
                        if (servers[j].Join(250))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Server thread[{0}] finished.", servers[j].ManagedThreadId);
                            servers[j] = null;
                            i--;    // decrement the thread watch count
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nServer threads exhausted, exiting.");
        }

        private static void ServerThread(object data)
        {
            NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer =
                new NamedPipeServerStream("testpipe", PipeDirection.InOut, numThreads);

            int threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

            // Wait for a client to connect
            pipeServer.WaitForConnection();

            Console.WriteLine("Client connected on thread[{0}].", threadId);
            try
            {
                // Read the request from the client. Once the client has 
                // written to the pipe its security token will be available.

                StreamString ss = new StreamString(pipeServer);

                // Verify our identity to the connected client using a 
                // string that the client anticipates.

                ss.WriteString("I am the one true server!");
                string filename = ss.ReadString();

                if (filename.ToString() == "Test")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("yes");
                    ss.WriteString("Done");
                }
                // Read in the contents of the file while impersonating the client.
                //ReadFileToStream fileReader = new ReadFileToStream(ss, filename);

                // Display the name of the user we are impersonating.
                //Console.WriteLine("Reading file: {0} on thread[{1}] as user: {2}.",
                //    filename, threadId, pipeServer.GetImpersonationUserName());
                //pipeServer.RunAsClient(fileReader.Start);
            }
            // Catch the IOException that is raised if the pipe is broken 
            // or disconnected. 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: {0}", e.Message);
            }
            pipeServer.Close();
        }
    }

    // Defines the data protocol for reading and writing strings on our stream 
    public class StreamString
    {
        private Stream ioStream;
        private UnicodeEncoding streamEncoding;

        public StreamString(Stream ioStream)
        {
            this.ioStream = ioStream;
            streamEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
        }

        public string ReadString()
        {
            int len = 0;

            len = ioStream.ReadByte() * 256;
            len += ioStream.ReadByte();
            byte[] inBuffer = new byte[len];
            ioStream.Read(inBuffer, 0, len);

            return streamEncoding.GetString(inBuffer);
        }

        public int WriteString(string outString)
        {
            byte[] outBuffer = streamEncoding.GetBytes(outString);
            int len = outBuffer.Length;
            if (len > UInt16.MaxValue)
            {
                len = (int)UInt16.MaxValue;
            }
            ioStream.WriteByte((byte)(len / 256));
            ioStream.WriteByte((byte)(len & 255));
            ioStream.Write(outBuffer, 0, len);
            ioStream.Flush();

            return outBuffer.Length + 2;
        }
    }

    // Contains the method executed in the context of the impersonated user 
    public class ReadFileToStream
    {
        private string fn;
        private StreamString ss;

        public ReadFileToStream(StreamString str, string filename)
        {
            fn = filename;
            ss = str;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            string contents = File.ReadAllText(fn);
            ss.WriteString(contents);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After a connect on your server you have to start waiting for aconnection again. Your current doesn't loop after a succesfull connection has been made.

Comment: +1, I don't see why this was downvoted..

Comment: @rene your answer is not really clear for me. Do you mean that I have to create a loop in the ServerThread Method? Because I thought this method is called on every connection try so that there is no loop necessary?

Comment: I don't see that... You start 4 server threads. Just lets step through one: Thread.Start invokes methode ServerThread. ServerThread creates an instance of pipeServer and then calls WaitForConnection() on it. When a connection comes in, it creates a StreamString  does a Write and a Read on it, then close the pipeServer. That is the last statement in ServerThread. As there is no more todo it ends its execution and with that the ServerThread has no work left to be done and can be Joined in your while loop. ServerThread is never invoked again...

Comment: @rene many thanks, this got me in the right direction. Inside the while loop I changed now the line: `servers[j] = null` to `servers[j] = new Thread(ServerThread); servers[j].Start();` Do you think I have to take care about the old thread or is the old thread automatically closed? Not that my clients have thousand of open threads ;-)

Comment: I think that works...You can also have a look at the async operations on namedpipeserver...like [BeginWaitForConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream.beginwaitforconnection.aspx)